# Looking for II7 configuration file location (root globalization)

Tags: configuration, iis-7, web-config, config

Configuration: IIS 7.0 / Windows Server 2008 SP2 / 32-bits

On the root node (the one named after the server name), when I look at Globalization, I see that some values are not default values.

I would like to find in which configuration file it is stored.

I already tried

```
  ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0....\Config\Machine.config
  ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0....\Config\Web.config
  ...\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

None of them contains anything about

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is nothing called Windows Server 2007. Maybe you are using Windows Server 2008.

Second, IIS Manager for 7.x reads ASP.NET settings from v2.0 folders, not v4.0. Only IIS Manager for 8.x and above read from v4.0.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about Windows version. I thought it was odd but since I wasn't the one who installed it, I thought maybe it was it (it was only the copyright. The About Windows menu gave me Windows Server 2008). I fixed it.

Comment: You are also right about the config location which makes me wonder: is it worthless to use IIS 7 to set my configs if my pools are set to run Fx4? If not, how does it work?

Comment: @bkqc what you see from IIS Manager is what IIS Manager loads from v2.0 folders. However, your v4.0 apps merely read settings from v4.0 folders. So if you really want to view/change settings for your ASP.NET 4.x apps, you have to manually open machine.config/root web.config from v4.0 folders and make the changes there. IIS Manager won't help in that case.

Comment: I did some additional testing and the part about .NET4 configuration is not totally true. In fact, after some trial and error trying to figure out where did children sites defined their own value, I discovered that the ROOT NODE always uses FX2 config files BUT children sites use config files from their respective pool Framework version. I think you should refine your answer. Thanks again for helping me see the light in all this!